# FreeStyle won't appear in Blender Render, pictures below?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, freestyle

It worked before but I can't seem to get it to work again, this is the model I was using [this anime tutorial](//www.youtube.com/watch?v=MGs6Zv1pl9o)  I'm not using Makehuman like him though I'm using Fuse Mixamo. I've done this before and it worked fine I've tired this with 3 models and it won't appear for some reason.

[image]

These are my settings, I've gone through the video to make sure they were correct
I'm using blender 2.72, Blender Render not Cycles. 
[image]

Comment: Welcome! Is the Line Set enabled (the checkbox is not visible in the screenshot)? Do you have the same problem with simpler scene like the default one?

Comment: You are allowed to post max two hyperlinks at a time in the question field as a "new" user. http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user As the video is public on YT, I think that it's all fine.

Comment: Thanks for answering I'm not sure where is the Line Set enabled located?

Comment: Just above what you can see in the second picture you posted. Render layer tab >> Freestyle line set.

Comment: is the master "freestyle" checkbox enabled in the render options panel, is it?

Answer (score 1):

Another issue is the render buffering. Try deactivating Performance/Save Buffers to force Blender to redraw the Freestyle overlay.

Make sure to turn this function off.

[image: Turn this function OFF]